# Decrease Tableview selectable area in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iJ7m.png)Hi in my project there is a requirement to show table row selection(blue color) only half of the row.Is there any way to do this.

The selected cell should be in blue color and remaining all are in white. Please help me to achive this also.I dont want to reload table because many images are there loading from server.If reload again again it will slow down performance.

[Please see the image after selection the cell should appear like this]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iJ7m.png)

Comment: r u using the custom cell or else

Answer (score 0):

You can set `selectedBackgroundView` property of `UITableViewCell` with a view whose half is blue.

Answer (score 0):

In didSelectRowAtIndexpath  get cell ..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
 UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 // add view as per your according to need  in cell 

 UIView * myCellAccessoryView = [UIview alloc] init];

 // set frame of myCellAccessoryView as per your need ..
 myCellAccessoryView.backGroundColor = // set color as you need .

// and add in cell 
 [cell.contentView addSubView :myCellAccessoryView];

}
```

hope it helps you ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc]init];
backView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width/2, cell.frame.size.height);
backView.backgroundColor    =[UIColor blueColor];
[cell addSubview:backView];
```

This will create a blue color background view.

Comment: the questioner need the half width not height , can you csutomize your answer